# How can I simulate onClose method for a toast

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, toastr

I am using react-toastify for displaying toasts and one specific call that I want to unit test is

```
toast.success("You did well", {onClose: ()=> {window.location = "/home", console.log("Going home")}}
```

How can I spy on onClose method? Using below does not work because onClose is not a method of toast.success. I want to check if onClose is perform correct redirection.

```
spyOn(toast.success, onClose)
```

Comment: check https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/blob/master/src/__tests__/toast.js to see how library authors are testing `toast` functional helpers

Comment: Yeah I checked that but in my unit test case, I am mounting another component that shows/invokes a toast. The Container is a parent and I am do not understand that in such a case how can I get a handle on toast unmount method.